# How do I perform a variance operation between two dictionaries with different keys in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Everything I have found so far teaches only how to perform operations with the same Keys.

I would like to perform a numpy var on two different `dict`, then have the result be the value in the resulting dict and the key be the concatenation of the two keys used.

Ive tried serval different ways (trying to be efficient) to no avail. this is my current method.

```
dict1 = {'mall': [[928046, 47653]],
     'place': [[95446, 4233]],
     'thing': [[76546, 4345463]]}

dict2 = {'sam': [[4236, 44323]],
     'dan': [[8676, 34223]],
     'red': [[4236, 49684323]],
     'bob': [[654, 42345]],
     'sharon': [[321, 454234]],
     'ashley': [[4958843, 4343423]]}

var_dict = {(dict1[key] + dict2[key]): np.var((np.array(dict1.[key], dict2[key])) for key in dict1}
```

Comment: Could you specify what output you expect for the above input?

Comment: Do you want every combo? `Sam-Mall` `Sam-Place` `Sam-Thing` etc?

Comment: @GrantMcCloskey Yes I would like every combo, but the other way. i.e: Mall-Sam, mall-dan, mall-red, mall-bob, mall-charon, mall-ashely, place-sam, place-dan , etc

Comment: @tif some thing like this with the var as the value dict2 = {'mall-sam': 5,
     'mall-dan': 23,
     'mall-red':2,
     'mall-bob': 8,
     'mall-sharon': 9,
     'mall-ashley': 21}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly this code achieves what you asked:

```
import numpy as np

dict1 = {'mall': [[928046, 47653]],
         'place': [[95446, 4233]],
         'thing': [[76546, 4345463]]}

dict2 = {'sam': [[4236, 44323]],
         'dan': [[8676, 34223]],
         'red': [[4236, 49684323]],
         'bob': [[654, 42345]],
         'sharon': [[321, 454234]],
         'ashley': [[4958843, 4343423]]}

result = {(k1, k2): np.var(v1 + v2) for k1, v1 in dict1.iteritems() for k2, v2 in
          dict2.iteritems()}
```

Basically you need to iterate over the two dictionaries, join the list and then pass the result to np.var (this is what the last line does). This code is for Python 2.7 for Python3, substitute `.iteritems()`
 by .`items()`.

Comment: `'-'.join((k1, k2)): np.var(v1 + v2)` to avoid key tuple

Comment: should the dict1.iteritems() be dict1.items()? Im getting errors